# How to Access client project directory from web api in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

My Asp.net project is Multi layer project like `DAL`,`DATA`,`WebApi` .... etc.

My UI layer is in the combination of `html5`,`angularjs` etc.

There is no server side code in my UI layer.

My UI layer communicate via rest api with `webapi` layer .

Now I want folder list of my UI layer. How can I do that ? as client script has no power to do that.So, only left with web api layer. Is it possible that i can get directory list of UI layer from my web api layer ?

If yes, How can I do That ? If No, What's the alternative and how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can not access folder from another project under same solution without

1. Reference dll
2. share folder
3. maintain resource file
4. fixed path
5. If you want to access file then create link file

I think Shared folder is a better solution :

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324267
```

OR

Use fixed path into your web config and read that when you will need. I wrote some code to get folder name within same project.

**API Method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<string> GetFolderNames(int id)
{
    //FIND ALL FOLDERS IN FOLDER with in own project
    string location = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("parent folder name");

    //For fixed path location will be like as string location =@"E:\Target Folder\";

    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(location);
    var folderList = new List<string>();

    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        //LOAD FOLDERS 
        folderList.Add(g.FullName);
    }

    return folderList;
}
```

**JS Method:**

```
 //service name
 var serviceName = 'api controller name';
 //full url
 var remoteService = "Full Url" + serviceName;
 //parameters
 var params = {
     id: 1,
 };
 //get method calling
 $http({
     url: remoteService + '/GetFolderNames',
     method: 'GET',
     params: params,
 }).then(function (result) {
     //required result
     var r = result;
 }).
 catch (function (e) {
     throw e;
 });
```

**Use of server map path:**

```
Server.MapPath(".") returns D:\WebApps\shop\products
Server.MapPath("..") returns D:\WebApps\shop
Server.MapPath("~") returns D:\WebApps\shop
Server.MapPath("/") returns C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
Server.MapPath("/shop") returns D:\WebApps\shop
```